# Expected type: java.lang.Integer, actual value: java.lang.Short

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to do this:

```
public List getInventarioNode(){
                String sql = "select n.nid, n.nnm, n.nhwtype, n.nstate, n.ipaddress, n.ipaddressrouterid, n.eswversion, u.unhwtype, u.unslot, m.mpos, m.mhwtype from node n, unit u, module m where n.nid*=u.nid and n.nid*=m.nid and u.nid*=m.nid and u.unnr*=m.unnr and n.nhwtype in (10020, 10021, 10022, 10023, 10002, 10017, 10001) and m.mpos not between 11 and 10000";
                List resultWithAliasedBean = session.createSQLQuery(sql).setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Node.class)).list();
                return resultWithAliasedBean;
    }
```

But I am getting this error:

```
11567 [AWT-EventQueue-0] ERROR org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor - HHH000123: IllegalArgumentException in class: br.com.model.Node, setter method of property: mpos
11568 [AWT-EventQueue-0] ERROR org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor - HHH000091: Expected type: java.lang.Integer, actual value: java.lang.Short
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter for property [br.com.model.Node.mpos (expected type = java.lang.Integer)]; target = [br.com.model.Node@18f6f48], property value = [0]
```

Node Class:

//I tried to change the type of mpos and mhwtype to int, but it didnt work because the first row is null. In the database both are smallint, and can be null.

```
private Integer mpos;
private Integer mhwtype; 

public Node(){}

public Integer getMpos() {
        return mpos;
    }

    public void setMpos(Integer mpos) {
        this.mpos = mpos;
    }

    public Integer getMhwtype() {
        return mhwtype;
    }

    public void setMhwtype(Integer mhwtype) {
        this.mhwtype = mhwtype;
    }
```

Comment: wow, this code is hard on the eyes! start by parametizing your `List`.

Comment: What is the data type of those fields in your database?

Comment: Can you show us some of the `br.com.model.Node` class, specifically the declaration of the `mpos` field?

Comment: Yes, look the update please

Comment: I dont know how to do this Snake

Comment: @Murilo it woudl be something like: `List<YourExpectedDataType> resultWithAliasedBean = .... ;`  This tells your `List` what data types it should be expecting.

Comment: ok, but it would be List<Node> ?

Comment: @Murilo I think Nappa is on the right track, you possibly are trying to use the wrong datatype from what your database expects for that column, or are trying to return out of it a different data type than what your code is expecting... basically a datatype mismatch it seems.

Comment: I put List<Node> resultWithAliasedBean, but I am still getting the same error

Comment: Snake, My database gives me a smallint, the problem is that the first row is a null value, so if I put a int type in java code I get an error from Null.

Comment: Mpos and Mhwtype are smallint in database, and they are nullable

Comment: you have `getMpos()` returning an `Integer` but your database is giving your a `Short` (in java terms). i would expect it to autobox into an `Integer`, but maybe see if changing to a `Short` helps?

Comment: Snake, when I did a select withou bringing a null value it works. But when it brings a null value, the set method with a int parameter it says: Null value was assigned to a property of primitive type setter of br.com.model.Node.mpos. And when I change the parameter to Integer it says that it is expecting a short type and not a Integer

Comment: Snake, I solved the problem. I just change Integer to Short. I was very confused and it was simple :/. Thanks a lot !